# Django or Ruby on Rails in an embedded webserver environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, embedded

The particular situation I am looking at is a Lighttp webserver embedded in a hardware device, similar to your home network router. So you can imagine, the footprint is small in both memory availability and processing power.

The two choices offered to me for developing the web application used to configure this device is either Django or Ruby on Rails. This is a telecommuncations device and the web application will configure settings on it as well as manage contact directories and the ability make outbound and accept inbound calls to and from the device. The application will also be used to upgrade the device.

The current interface uses a Flash front-end and php backend. But they want to get rid of both Flash and PHP.

So what is the prevailing opinion out here for this situation?

Comment: If you know neither ruby nor python, I'd suggest to get to know both of them and get the feel of development on either platforms. Then the choice would be clearer.

Comment: Both python and ruby have a high memory and performance overhead, none of them will fit if you need a small footprint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462571/are-there-benchmarks-comparing-the-respective-memory-usage-of-django-rails-and-p

Comment: No consumer-level 'home network router' has enough RAM or Flash to run RoR or Django. I've successfully used libcgic in this application. Also consider a Lua web framework, which is more likely to fit.

Answer (score 0):

> So you can imagine, the footprint is small in both memory availability
>   and processing power.

No chance you will see that with Python or Ruby. I think you need to provide more details for us to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Your question as asked ("prevailing opinion") is off-topic for stackoverflow (no definitive answer).  However, I think what you're really asking is "are there any technical obstacles or benefits to using RoR vs. Django on a device with only XYZ resources?"

We can't answer that without knowing exactly what the limitations of your device are.  It could be that neither framework is suitable, or either one would be fine (the latter is more likely, if someone has 'offered' you these as choices).

You may find answers to this question helpful:
[Are there benchmarks comparing the respective memory usage of django, rails and PHP frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462571/are-there-benchmarks-comparing-the-respective-memory-usage-of-django-rails-and-p)